# Various columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to write a SQL statement to create a list of countries with the number of normal customers and corporate customers. So it should have 3 columns `Country`, `Normal customer`, and `corporate customer`.

`Country` column includes all countries from the customer table. The Normal and corporate customer display the number of normal and the number of corporate customers respectively in each country.

The customer table contains columns `CustomerID`, `company`, `country`

And the output should look like this:

```
Country   | Normal Customer | Corporate Customer 
----------------------------------------------------------------
Japan     | 25              |    2
Korea     | 23              |    0
```

So far I have only got this but I just need to know If I'm sort of going in the right track, it's not complete yet.

```
SELECT  
    Country, company
 COUNT 
FROM 
    Customer 
WHERE 
    Company IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that when there is no company present that it's a 'normal' customer here;

```
SELECT
Country
,SUM(CASE WHEN Company IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Normal_Customer
,SUM(CASE WHEN Company IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Corporate_Customer
FROM Customer
GROUP BY Country
```

Comment: happy to help :) I've just edited as I missed out a couple of commas.